# DynamoDB: clarification needed for hot partition for GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-global

The following example is representation if GSI example  from [AWS site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)

| GameTitle(GSI PK) | TopScore (GSI SK) |
| --- | --- |
| "Galaxy Invader" | 0 |
| "Galaxy Invader" | 2317 |

I am wondering if having GameTitle as the GSI PK is a good choice because it could potentially create a hot key if the "Galaxy Invader" has lot of users playing at the same time.

I would appreciate any clarification on this

TIA

Researched to understand how GSI works

Answer (score 0):

A Global Secondary Index must follow the same partition limits that a DynamoDB table has:

- Write Capacity Units (WCU): 1000
- Read Capacity Units (RCU): 3000

*Let's make an assumption that all of your item sizes are less than 1KB.*

If you write to your DynamoDB table more than 1000 times per second with items containing a single value for `GameTitle` then you will have exceed the 1000 WCU partition limit. As a result, your index will tell your base table to stop accepting writes for that partition, which in turn will cause DynamoDB to return throttling status code 400, this concept is known as GSI backpressure.

If you believe there is a possibility that you will in the future require more than 1000 writes per second to a single `GameTitle` then I suggest you implement [GSI Write Sharding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-sharding.html). This technique can help you overcome any potential throttling caused by GSI backpressure.